# Skip empty files inside zip files

Tags: r

I am reading a lot of `.csv` files inside a `.zip` file with the following code

```
for (i in unzip("data.zip", list = TRUE)) {
    read.csv(unz("data.zip", i))
}
```

The problem is that some of `.csv` files are empty that leads to `no lines available in input` error that causes the execution of the loop be interrupted. How can I skip those empty files?

Comment: Currently your code does not save any information from any of the files since the csv file is just printed the console. Something like flist <- unzip("data.zip", list=TRUE) returns a data frame containing information on the size of each file. You could use that to create a vector of file names and then remove the names that are empty files. The simplest way would be to use `unzip` to extract all of the files into a directory of your choosing and then use lapply to extract them into a list of data frames. It will make things much easier in the long run.

Comment: @dcarlson OMG :-O, you are right. I did not notice `unzip("data.zip", list = TRUE)` return length and date alongside name of files. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
flist <- unzip("data.zip", list=TRUE)
```

Now flist$Length gives you the length of each file, so e.g.

```
keep <- flist$Length > 100  # or some other value that indicates the file has no data
```

Now you can read the nonempty ones and save them to a list:

```
AllFiles <- lapply(flist$Name[keep], read.csv)
```